# quering a database in visual studio

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I use local Access database in C# project. I need to develop a complex SQL query, but I'm a bit stuck.  My table structure is:

```
Student:
(PK)TagID  StudentID (FK)CourseID
4855755    HUJ564334    25
4534664    RED231232    33

Course
(PK)CourseID CourseName
25           Computer Science
33           Biology

CourseID-ModuleID
(FK)CourseID (FK)ModuleID
25              CMP2343
25              CMP3456
33              BIO3422
33              BIO2217

Module
(PK)ModuleID ModuleName
CMP2343      Networking
CMP3456      Databases
BIO3422      Human body
BIO2217      Genetics

ModuleID-SessionID
(FK)ModuleID (FK)SessionID
CMP2343      1ACMP2343
CMP2343      2ACMP2343 
CMP3456      1ACMP3456
CMP3456      2ACMP3456
BIO3422      1ABIO3422      
BIO3422      2ABIO3422
BIO2217      1ABIO2217      
BIO2217      2ABIO2217 

Session
(PK)SessionID  SessionDate      SessionTimeStart SessionTimeEnd
1ACMP2343      09/05/2013          12:00 AM         14:00 PM
2ACMP2343      05/05/2013          09:00 AM         11:00 PM
1ACMP3456      15/05/2013          12:00 AM         13:00 PM
2ACMP3456      01/05/2013          10:00 AM         13:00 PM
1ABIO3422      30/04/2013          11:00 AM         13:00 PM
2ABIO3422      01/04/2013          14:00 AM         16:00 PM
1ABIO2217      12/05/2013          16:00 AM         18:00 PM
2ABIO2217      03/05/2013          12:00 AM         14:00 PM   

Attendance
(FK)TagID (FK)SessionID ScanningTime
```

I would like my query to find a "current" SessionID (by looking up the date and time of the session, saved in DB) for the given TagID, and display TagID and SessionID in the Attendance table, along with the time of scanning.

I use a folowing method to set up a connection with a DB, and display the data in dataGridView2:

```
public void setSQL()
        {
            string ConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\jasper\\Desktop\\AutoReg\\AutoReg\\AutoReg.accdb;";

            OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);
            MyConn.Open();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            //query to ask
            string query = @"SELECT s.TagID, se.SessionID, " + "'" +
            DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss tt") + @"' AS scanningTime 

                            FROM Student s,
                            CourseID-ModuleID cm,
                            ModuleID-SessionID ms,
                            Session se

                            WHERE 1=1 
                            AND s.TagID = 4820427
                            AND s.CourseID = cm.CourseID
                            AND ms.ModuleID = cm.ModuleID
                            AND ms.SessionID = se.SessionID
                            AND se.SessionDate = Date();";

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, MyConn);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);

                adapter.Fill(ds);
                dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                MyConn.Close();

        }
```

When I execute the above code, I get an error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).
```

I am sure that the method structure is OK as I can run and display a simple query, such as: `"SELECT * FROM Student";`

Comment: I think the problem you have is with `se.SessionDate = Date();`. I don't think Date() is a SQL Function. Try adding the datetime like you have for the scanning time (just without the time part)

Comment: Doesn't work, I'm sure that Date() is a SQL function...

Comment: What Database Server are you using?

Comment: @Greg look at the connectionstring

Comment: Have you tried removing that scanningTime field?

Comment: local Access database, OleDb namespace

Comment: What is the reason to not use JOIN ?

Comment: probably my lack of skills, could you present an example?
And yes, I have tried removing ScanningTime...

Comment: I will try adding an answer to use better formatting. If it doesn't work tell me and I will delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to let this query work. I have resolved it adding the square brackets around the table names. First, the SESSION word is a reserved keyword in ms-access jet SQL, so you need to encapsulate that name in square brackets. The weird part however is that you need to add square brackets also around the `CourseID-ModuleID` and `ModuleID-SessionID` tables. The minus character is not well accepted by the MS-Access - OleDb engine, infact if you try a simple `"SELECT * FROM CourseID-ModuleID"` you get a syntax error that disappears if you put the square brackets around the table name

```
string query = @"SELECT s.TagID, se.SessionID, '" + 
               DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss tt") + 
               "' AS scanningTime " + 
               "FROM (((Student s " + 
               " LEFT JOIN [CourseID-ModuleID] cm ON s.CourseID = cm.CourseID) " + 
               " LEFT JOIN [ModuleID-SessionID] ms ON ms.ModuleID = cm.ModuleID) " + 
               " LEFT JOIN [Session] se ON ms.SessionID = se.SessionID) " + 
               "WHERE s.TagID = 4820427 AND se.SessionDate = Date()";
```

Using the Access interface the square bracket are automatically added to the query text and so the error is not immediately visible.

As a side note, that `se.SessionData = Date()` effectively remove any result because there is no SessionDate equals to the current date.

Comment: I am curious about this error. Do you have a spare db to post on some filesharing site?

Comment: sorry no, but I'm happy to email it to you. Could you send me you email as prv msg?

Comment: Sign up for a free account (Dropbox, GDrive, SkyDrive, MediaFire etc) sorry but I don't post my email address on public sites.

Comment: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EA4BB1476E7C00EA!142

This is the DB I'm using...
Please let me know if you can access it

Comment: Steve, any luck with my question?

Comment: OK I have made it work. That's really weird put square brackets around the table names. I update the answer now

Comment: This is very usefull, thank you, but still I cannot see the query results, even after updating the date in database

Comment: I finally got it partially working by removing AND se.SessionDate = Date(). Could it be due to the date format? Thank you so much! Marked as answered!